# Why isn't transliteration from Urdu to Latin working properly in icu4c?

Tags: icu, transliteration, latin

I'm trying to convert this line of Urdu to Latin, and then converting the Latin characters to ASCII (by removing the accents, etc) but it seems to be missing some characters.

Why are there non latin characters ("ہ", "ے", etc) still there?

```
$ uconv -x 'Any-Latin'
دفعہ 1: تمام انسان آزاد اور حقوق و عزت کے اعتبار سے برابر پیدا ہوۓ ہیں۔ انہیں ضمیر اور عقل ودیعت ہوئی ہے۔ اس لئے انہیں ایک دوسرے کے ساتھ بھائی چارے کا سلوک کرنا چاہئے

dfʿہ 1: tmạm ạnsạn ậzạd ạwr ḥqwq w ʿzt ḵے ạʿtbạr sے brạbr py̰dạ ہwے̉ ہy̰ں۔ ạnہy̰ں ḍmy̰r ạwr ʿql wdy̰ʿt ہwỷy̰ ہے۔ ạs lỷے ạnہy̰ں ạy̰ḵ dwsrے ḵے sạtھ bھạỷy̰ cẖạrے ḵạ slwḵ ḵrnạ cẖạہỷے
```

Why is the transliterator `Any-ASCII` not converting to ASCII?

```
$ uconv -x 'Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII'
دفعہ 1: تمام انسان آزاد اور حقوق و عزت کے اعتبار سے برابر پیدا ہوۓ ہیں۔ انہیں ضمیر اور عقل ودیعت ہوئی ہے۔ اس لئے انہیں ایک دوسرے کے ساتھ بھائی چارے کا سلوک کرنا چاہئے

dfʿہ 1: tmam ansan azad awr hqwq w ʿzt kے aʿtbar sے brabr pyda ہwے̉ ہyں۔ anہyں dmyr awr ʿql wdyʿt ہwyy ہے۔ as lyے anہyں ayk dwsrے kے satھ bھayy charے ka slwk krna chaہyے
$ uconv -x 'Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII' -t latin1
دفعہ 1: تمام انسان آزاد اور حقوق و عزت کے اعتبار سے برابر پیدا ہوۓ ہیں۔ انہیں ضمیر اور عقل ودیعت ہوئی ہے۔ اس لئے انہیں ایک دوسرے کے ساتھ بھائی چارے کا سلوک کرنا چاہئے

Conversion from Unicode to codepage failed at output byte position 2. Unicode: 02bf Error: Invalid character found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see what those characters are with this command:

`uconv -x 'Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII' --to-callback escape-c -t ascii`

- `-t ascii`   : convert the output to actual ASCII. Not just latin1.
- `--to-callback escape-c` :  anything that wasn't convertable, goes through the 'escape' callback

which gives us this result:

`df\u02BF\u06C1 1: tmam ansan azad awr hqwq w \u02BFzt k\u06D2 a\u02BFtbar s\u06D2 brabr pyda \u06C1w\u06D2\u0309 \u06C1y\u06BA\u06D4 an\u06C1y\u06BA dmyr awr \u02BFql wdy\u02BFt \u06C1wyy \u06C1\u06D2\u06D4 as ly\u06D2 an\u06C1y\u06BA ayk dwsr\u06D2 k\u06D2 sat\u06BE b\u06BEayy char\u06D2 ka slwk krna cha\u06C1y\u06D2`

So, `U+06C1 HEH GOAL` for instance isn't transliterated.  You could file a CLDR ticket.

Actually, there's already this one:  http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/4387

Once there's an Urdu-Latin transliteration, then you can use `ur-Latin` instead of just `Any-Latin`.  That way Urdu specific rules are used and not just Arabic script rules.

I'd follow up on ticket 4387 if I were you.